# COnditional expectation and expectation with indicator function

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

I need to compute $$\mathbb{E}\left[X^n|X>c\right]$$

I am quite sure that I can rewrite as:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[X^n|X>c\right]=\frac{\mathbb E\left[X^nI_{X>c}\right]}{P(X>c)}$$

However, I am not so sure on how I should contine.
My guess is that $\mathbb E\left[X^nI_{X>c}\right]$ should be
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^nI_{x>c}f(x)dx=\int_c^{+\infty}x^nf(x)dx$$

And the final solution:
$$\frac{\int_c^{+\infty}x^nf(x)dx}{P(X>c)}$$
But I am not so sure, could some of you kindly help me?

Moreover, in the case I want to change variables and suppose that $c=F^{-1}(K)$, could you give me a hint about that?

Comment: It is $$( \int_c^{+\infty}x^nf(x)dx) / (\int_c^{+\infty}f(x)dx) $$

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much I forgot one part. Could you kindly check now my questions and help me with the second part? Tank you very much

Comment: If $c=F^{-1}(K)$ then the denominator becomes $1-F(F^{-1}(K))=K$. Numerator does not simplify.

Comment: So there is no way to to some variable changes i.e. in terms of numerator: $$ \int_c^{+\infty}x^nf(x)dx=\int_c^{+\infty}x^ndF(x)$$ and find a way to introduce F(x)=y and rewrite the integrals as $$\int_K^{1}\cdots dy$$?

Comment: You will get $f(F^{-1}(y) (F^{-1}(y))'dy$, etc. Unless $F^{-1}$ has  a nice form this change of variables is not useful.

Comment: For example, suppose n=2,  $$ \int_c^{+\infty}x^2 dF(x)= \int_c^{+\infty}x*x dF(x)$$ can it be rewritten as $$\int_K^{1} F^{-1}(y)*F^{-1}(y)* dy$$??
I am sorry for all this questions
I need to express as a formula of F^-1 to show some results as F^-1 has some specific properties and comment. That is the main reason why I need to do that

Comment: I did not understand why the f(..) and your computation, I think we can write it as a product from i to m for x. May I ask you if you could write your computations in an answer?